# blender 2.92 python overriding

Tags: python, blender

I have seen quite a few questions regarding this issue, and I have not been able to wrap my head around it.

So here is a concrete example.

I create a cube and in edit mode I add loopcuts. No sweat!

I copy the code from the info window and I try it out in a script and I get the ominous RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh error message.

I understand now that it is about first giving python the right context by overriding. And alas, I do not know how  to do it!

Here is the code:

```
import bpy
import os

os.system("cls")

# remove the default cube...
objs = bpy.data.objects
for obj in objs:
    if obj.name.find("Cube") == 0:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)

# add a cube!
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
# do something to it to be sure that we have it...
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].scale[0] = 10

# THE CODE BELOW GIVES THE RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide.poll() expected a view3d region & editmesh error message.

# What is the override code I have to use to fix it????????

bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":16, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE', "object_index":0, "edge_index":4, "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":0, "single_side":False, "use_even":False, "flipped":False, "use_clamp":True, "mirror":True, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":True, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy      
import os

os.system("cls")


objs = bpy.data.objects
for obj in objs:
    if obj.name.find("Cube") == 0:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)

# add a cube!
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
# do something to it to be sure that we have it...
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].scale[0] = 10



for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    override = {'area': area, 'region': region, 'edit_object':bpy.context.edit_object}


                    bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(override,MESH_OT_loopcut={"number_cuts":16, "smoothness":0, "falloff":'INVERSE_SQUARE', "object_index":0, "edge_index":4, "mesh_select_mode_init":(True, False, False)}, TRANSFORM_OT_edge_slide={"value":0, "single_side":False, "use_even":False, "flipped":False, "use_clamp":True, "mirror":True, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "correct_uv":True, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
```

Comment: Could you please detail what changes you've made to the OP's snippet and why they solve their issue?

Comment: vcleanall, are you aware that you can comment on your own posts and [edit] them?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I had posted this question also on blenderartists the same day, where I got the same answer rather quickly, and by now I believe that I have understood what it is about.